# using projections on multiple columns - joined tables

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, mapping

Good day.

So i have mapping 
   @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "discount_fares_id_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "discount_fares_id_sequence",
        sequenceName = "discount_fares_id_seq",
        allocationSize = 1
    )
    private Long id;

```
@Column
private Long discount;

@Column(name = "fare_code", length = 255)
private String fareCode;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "aircompany_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_discfares_ref_aircompany_id"))
private AircompanyRB aircompanyId;
```

how do i use projections to extract only

discountFare id
discount
fareCode
and aircompany_id   (the key of AircompanyRB)

So basically all the fields of DiscountFares plus only key of AircompanyRB?

I tried

```
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(DiscountFares.class)
        .createCriteria("aircompanyId")
        .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("id"))
        .add(Projections.property("discount"))
        .add(Projections.property("fareCode")));

    List<DiscountFares> result = criteria.getExecutableCriteria(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).list();
```

but it throws exception saying AircompanyRB doesnt have a field "discount"
(yes, it does not-  DiscountFares have)

thank you very much!
any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're making your life difficult by using a Criteria query instead of a dead simple HQL query:

```
select df.id, df.discount, df.fareCode, ac.id 
from DiscountFares df
left join df.aircompanyId ac
```

Now, if you really want to use a Criteria, just translate the above query:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(DiscountFares.class, "df");
c.createAlias("df.aircompanyId", "ac", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
c.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.property("df.id"))
    .add(Projections.property("df.discount"))
    .add(Projections.property("df.fareCode"))
    .add(Projections.property("ac.id")));
```

Comment: thank you that's awesome, but i need to get an object DiscountFare,

Comment: Then use `select df, ad.id from from DiscountFares df ...`